# Generate random number/text in logstash

Tags: random, logstash, logstash-file

Is there any inbuilt way to generate random text (of certain length) or number (of certain range) in logstash input/filer plugins? or should we write one in ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the [generator input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-generator.html) could work for you.

For more variety in your messages, ruby:

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
          begin

            # random 10-letter string
            # event['message'] = rand(36**10).to_s(36)

            # random integer
            event['message'] = rand(100).to_s()

          rescue Exception => e
            event['ruby_exception'] = 'EEK: ' + e.message
          end
        "
    }
}
```

Comment: no, its not. "generator input" actually needs set of lines and number of times those lines have to be generated as input events. thats not what i want.

Comment: Yes, the ruby{} filter allows you to run arbitrary ruby code.

Comment: The event API has changed, you now need use the set method
```event.set('message', rand(36**10).to_s(36))```

Hope this helps anyone else searching this